# Is it possible to access Voice Memos from site icloud.com?

Tags: iphone, icloud, voice-memo

I'm using Apple app Voice Memos on my iPhone. In the iPhone settings I have iCloud Drive enabled and as well as Voice Memos. But on the site https://www.icloud.com I can't see my saved voice memos. Should they be there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to log into iCloud website and access voice memos. What the setting implies that the iCloud servers are used to backup and store the voice memo recordings, but you'll need the Voice Memos app on iOS/iPadOS or macOS device to access them.

Comment: I thought Voice Memos used to exist on the icloud.com website before?
Am I mistaken ?

Comment: Is it updated in 2023?